# Setting up a new separate navigationcontroller in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app runs using a navigationcontroller, but there's a button on the home screen which will take the user to a preferences viewcontroller. I want the preferences to open and use it's own navigation controller, so there won't be a 'back' style button and it'll slide up from the bottom (like a modalviewcontroller). How do i add a separate navigation controller to my preferences screen for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create your navigation controller and present it modally - this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952109/is-it-possible-to-create-a-uinavigationcontroller-within-a-modalpopup) is mostly what you might do first.

Remember to account for dismissing the [modal view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) with say a Close or Done button in the navigation bar.